# Why doesn't my flex work in my css? I've tried to use grid but it still doesn't work

Tags: css, reactjs

```
const PictureBox = () => {
    **this is an array of pictures**
    const allPictures = [
        { before: Sofa1, after: Sofa2 },
        { before: Sofa1, after: Sofa2 },
        { before: Sofa1, after: Sofa2 },
        { before: Sofa1, after: Sofa2 }
    ];
   
    **setting the state**
    const [x, setX] = useState(0)

    **functions that slide left and right based on the state**
    const goLeft = () => {
        x === 200 * (allPictures.length - 1) ? setX(0) : setX(x + 200)
        x === 200 * (allPictures.length - 1) ? setX(0) : setX(x + 200)
    }
    const goRight = () => {
        x === 0 ? setX(200 * (allPictures.length - 1)) : setX(x - 200)
        x === 0 ? setX(200 * (allPictures.length - 1)) : setX(x - 200)
    }

    return (
        <div className="slider"  >
            <div>
                 {allPictures.map((img, index) => {
                return (
                   
                    <div className="slide" style={{ transform:`translateX(${x}%)`}} key={index}>
                        <img src={img.before}  alt="hello" height='100%' width='50%' />
                        <img src={img.after}  alt="hello" height='100%' width='50%' />
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            </div>
           
            <button id='goleft' onClick={goLeft}>left</button>
            <button id='goright' onClick={goRight} >right</button>
        </div>
    )
}


export default PictureBox;
```

Styling:

```
.slider {
    height: 450px;
    min-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
    border-radius: 12px; 
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.slide {
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    border: 1px double skyblue;
    background: rgb(2, 67, 95);
}
```

Comment: please put that code in the question body ^

Comment: @JenniferYaffe I added the styling to the question for you. Please remove the unnecessary comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.slider{
     height: 450px;
    min-width: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    flex: 1;
    border-radius: 12px;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}


.slide{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px double skyblue;
    background: rgb(2, 67, 95);
}
```

Comment: tried this and it works.... never knew about inline-flex

Answer (score -1):

Here are some things to explore

1. The `flex:1` css should be on the child not the parent so write that on .slide
2. Images are notorious to adding problems you can check if maybe there's an issue with the images not respecting flex `img{max-width:100%;max-height:100%}`

Comment: Does this work if you get rid of the images and put text and if you get rid of the tranformations?

Comment: i got rid of the images and transformations and it still doesn't work....

Comment: i used the same code in a different app and it works there... just here it doesn't work don't know why

Comment: Maybe you have some sort of parent CSS or you're overriding something? I suggest using chrome developer tools and trying to go over the different elements to see what's going on